# Splitting a String that contains emojis

Tags: java, regex, string, emoji

I need to split a String that may or may not contain emojis into a list of individual characters (keeping the emojis intact). Currently, and as is to be expected, any emoji is split into its individual parts.

```
String s = "abc";
String[] tokens = s.split("");
// tokens is ["?","?","?","?","a","b","c","?","?"]
// tokens should be ["","","a","b","c",""]
```

I want to keep project size to a minimum and with few to no dependencies, so I want to stay away from any 3rd party libraries. The exact output type doesn't matter too much, so long as I can at least iterate through the tokens in order.

Comment: Try `List<String> results = Pattern.compile("\\P{M}\\p{M}*+").matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.toList());` if you are using Java 9+. See [demo](https://ideone.com/5qFn1g)

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\p{So}|.", "$0\0").split("\0+");` should also work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may match and extract all Unicode code points consisting of base char and any amount of diacritics after that char:

```
\P{M}\p{M}*+
```

It matches any char other than a diacritic and then any 0+ diacritic chars.

[Java 9+ demo](https://ideone.com/5qFn1g):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "abc";
        List<String> results = Pattern.compile("\\P{M}\\p{M}*+").matcher(s)
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(results); 
    }
}
// => [, , a, b, c, ]
```

In earlier Java versions, you may use

```
import java.util.regex.*;
//.....
String s = "abc";
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\P{M}\\p{M}*+").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    results.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(results);  // => [, , a, b, c, ]
```

See [another Java demo](https://ideone.com/CbmkJM)

Comment: This doesn't work with emojis that are more than one code point. Example: https://emojipedia.org/man-rowing-boat/

Answer (score 0):

This may also work for you by matching [`\p{So}` (Other Symbol)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#OTHER_SYMBOL):

```
String s = "abc";
String[] arr = s.replaceAll("\\p{So}|.", "$0\0").split("\0+");
//=> { "", "", "a", "b", "c", "" }
```

Assuming your input doesn't contain NUL byte or `\0` otherwise you can just use this traditional way of matching and collecting:

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\P{So}|.").matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
   arr.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(arr);
//=> [, , a, b, c, ]
```